# scp and decompress file at the same time without saving it

Tags: linux, centos, rsync, tar, scp

I have been looking for an answer but nothing I have found has worked.

There's a tar file that will be on a cd on a different server that I need to transfer over to my server and decompress it all at the same time without an intermediate save.  the tar has multiple files, and they may be unknown.

How can I do this either from my server or from the other server?

I have explored this with scp, using tar and ssh, and tried to figure out with rsync..

any help is appreciated

Comment: `tar` is not a compressor, so you cannot decompress a tar file. You extract files from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On target system (where the files will be extracted):

```
cd /target/dir && ssh user@source_server "cat /path/to/your/file.tar" | tar -xvv
```

**OR**

From source server (where the tar file is located):

```
ssh user@target_system "cd /target/dir && tar -xvv" < /path/to/your/file.tar
```

---

Below there are some alternatives to play with (on target system), just to show fancier ways you may find interesting.

`scp` and bash process substitution (if available):

```
scp user@source_server:/path/to/your/file.tar >(cd /target/dir && tar -x)
```

`scp` and `/proc/self` (if available):

```
cd /target/dir && scp user@source_server:/path/to/your/file.tar /proc/self/fd/1 | tar -x
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes your file is a TAR archive.  It does not assume the TAR archive is zipped.  Commands/options may vary if the source file is actually something other than a standard TAR archive.

If you have a tar file on the source system, try the following:

```
cd /source/dir
cat somefile.tar | ssh user@target_host "cd /target/dir; tar xvf -"
```

Note the correct options on the `tar` command.  `x` to extract the tar, `v` for verbose (optional), `f` to specify a file (as opposed to a tape device).  You need the `-` at the end, as that will tar STDIN as the input for the tar command.  The tar command needs to happen within the quotes for the SSH command so the tar takes place on the target host not the local host.

From the target server, change the syntax a bit:

```
cd /target/dir
ssh user@source_host "cat /source/dir/somefile.tar" | tar xvf -
```